# Auto clear textbox after barcode input and passing the value to textfile

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my first time to use this barcode scanner hardware.After scanning, the value will stored into textfile(notepad). Im having a problem in auto clear the textbox after barcode input.I must click on the textbox to make another scanning.

```
public partial class Attendance : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Filename = "C:/Users/Nor  Asyraf  Mohd No/Documents/TestFile.txt";
        if (!File.Exists(Filename))
        {
            StreamWriter txtFile = File.CreateText(Filename);
            txtFile.Close();
            txtFile = File.AppendText(Filename);
            txtFile.WriteLine(txtText.Text);
            txtFile.Close();
        }
        else
            File.AppendAllText(Filename, txtText.Text + Environment.NewLine);
        txtText.Text = " ";
        lblError.Text = "Employee ID is saved";
        Response.AddHeader("REFRESH", "2;URL=Attendance.aspx");

    }


    protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
    }
}
```

Comment: Just focus the textbox on page load.

Comment: Got it. Thanks! @john